# pandas - python export as xls instead xlsx - ExcelWriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would like to export my pandas dataframe as a `xls` file and not a `xlsx`.

I use ExcelWriter.

I have done :

```
xlsxWriter = pd.ExcelWriter(str(outputName + "- Advanced.xls"))
```

Unfortunatly, nothing outputs.

I think I have to change the engine, but I don't know how?

Comment: won't [`df.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) passing the extension `.xls` work?

Comment: That sure does, you should post that as an answer @EdChum

Comment: @JulienMarrec done

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and pass the extension `.xls` as the file name:

```
df.to_excel(file_name_blah.xls)
```

pandas will use a different module to write the excel sheet out, note that it will require you to have the pre-requisite 3rd party module installed.

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you do need to explicitly call `pd.ExcelWriter`, here's how:

```
outputName = "xxxx"
xlsWriter = pd.ExcelWriter(str(outputName + "- Advanced.xls"), engine = 'xlwt')

# Convert the dataframe to an Excel Writer object.
test.to_excel(xlsWriter, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
xlsWriter.save()
```

**It's critical not to forget the `save()` command.** That was your problem.

Note that you can also set the `engine` directly like so: `test.to_excel('test.xls', engine='xlwt')`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to install the "xlwt" package on your active Env.

```
pip install xlwt
```

then just simply use the below code:

```
df.to_excel('test.xls')
```